# Access shows duplicates in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that calculates a total price and then determines whether a gift card should be given or not. The table shows as:

[image: Query Results]

[image: Design View]

```
SELECT
    Customer.First_Name,
    Customer.Last_Name,
    Order.Order_ID,
    Sum([Order Items].Quantity) AS [Total Items],
    Sum(([Quantity]*[Price])) AS [Total Price],
    IIf([Quantity]*[Price]>150,"Yes","No") AS [Gift Card]
FROM (Customer INNER JOIN [Order]
    ON Customer.Customer_ID = Order.Customer_ID)
INNER JOIN (Item INNER JOIN [Order Items]
    ON Item.Item_ID = [Order Items].Item_ID)
    ON Order.Order_ID = [Order Items].Order_ID
GROUP BY
    Customer.First_Name,
    Customer.Last_Name,
    Order.Order_ID,
    IIf([Quantity]*[Price]>150,"Yes","No");
```

It shows a duplicate field, how can I get rid of the duplicate field?

Comment: We need to see your query.  Then, tell us what logic you would use to choose between these two "duplicate" records.

Comment: It shows each item in the order individually when I want to group it by the total sum of the order. This is the query for giftcard: Gift Card: IIf([Quantity]*[Price]>150,"Yes","No"), and this is the query for Price: Total Price: Sum(([Quantity]*[Price]))

Comment: OK but can you show us a query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen SELECT Customer.First_Name, Customer.Last_Name, Order.Order_ID, Sum([Order Items].Quantity) AS [Total Items], Sum(([Quantity]*[Price])) AS [Total Price], IIf([Quantity]*[Price]>150,"Yes","No") AS [Gift Card]
FROM (Customer INNER JOIN [Order] ON Customer.Customer_ID = Order.Customer_ID) INNER JOIN (Item INNER JOIN [Order Items] ON Item.Item_ID = [Order Items].Item_ID) ON Order.Order_ID = [Order Items].Order_ID
GROUP BY Customer.First_Name, Customer.Last_Name, Order.Order_ID, IIf([Quantity]*[Price]>150,"Yes","No");

Comment: You still need to tell us which of the two records you want to keep, and why.

Comment: I need to keep all the records, its just that I need to combine those two records so that it adds up the total and isnt duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the yes/no label from your grouping.  This would guarantee that a given first/last name and order would always appear a single record in your result set.

```
SELECT
    Customer.First_Name,
    Customer.Last_Name,
    Order.Order_ID,
    SUM([Order Items].Quantity) AS [Total Items],
    SUM([Quantity]*[Price]) AS [Total Price],
    IIF(SUM([Quantity]*[Price]) > 150, "Yes", "No") AS [Gift Card]
FROM (Customer INNER JOIN [Order]
    ON Customer.Customer_ID = Order.Customer_ID)
INNER JOIN (Item INNER JOIN [Order Items]
    ON Item.Item_ID = [Order Items].Item_ID)
    ON Order.Order_ID = [Order Items].Order_ID
GROUP BY
    Customer.First_Name,
    Customer.Last_Name,
    Order.Order_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per data model you could do `group by` by the `customerid` and `orderid`

```
select c.customer_id, oi.order_id, SUM(oi.Qty) as TotalQty, SUM(oi.Qty*i.Price) as TotalPrice,
       IIF(SUM(oi.Qty*i.Price) > 150, 'Yes', 'No') as GiftApplicable
from customer c
inner join order o in o.customer_id = c.customer_id
inner join order_item oi on oi.order_id = o.order_id
inner join item i on i.item_id = oi.item_id
group by c.customer_id, oi.order_id
```